# CreateHashRouter paths all lead to home Page. Works fine with BrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, github-pages

I am trying to upload my project to GitHub Pages. BrowserRouter is not supported so I used HashRouter instead. My CreateBrowserRouter code works perfectly but as soon as I change it to CreateHashRouter all of the paths take me to home (). I noticed that the URL does change (for example if click on my Portfolio button the URL changes to "/Folio") however it remains in the home page.

**App**

```
import { GlobalProvider } from './context/GlobalState';
import {
  createHashRouter,
  RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";

const router = createHashRouter(
  [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Body/>,
  },
  {
    path: "RMP",
    element: <RMPPage/>
  },
  {
    path: "Folio",
    element: <FolioPage/>
  },
  {
    path: "Compare",
    element: <ComparePage/>
  },
  {
    path: "SubmitPage",
    element: <SubmitPage/>
  },
  {
    path: "RMPSubmit",
    element: <RMPSubmit/>
  },
  {
    path: "FolioEdit",
    element: <FolioEdit/>
  },
  {
    path: "ComparePageOne",
    element: <ComparePageOne/>
  },
  {
    path: "ComparePageTwo",
    element: <ComparePageTwo/>
  }
  
]);

/*
Global provider wrapped
Main App in index.ts (passed as prop here)
*/
function App() {
  return (
    <GlobalProvider>
    <div className="App">
      <RouterProvider router={router}/>
    </div>
    </GlobalProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Index**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <App />
);
```

**Here is my Website Navigation Bar (Header)**

```
export let Header = (props:HeaderProps) => {
    return(
        <div className="headerStyle">
            <a className="titleStyle" href="/">{props.title}</a>
            <a className="navBarStyle" href='/folio'> Folio </a>
            <a className="navBarStyle" href='/RMP'> RMP </a>
            <a className="navBarStyle" href='/Compare'> Compare </a>
            <Search/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Like I said, it works perfectly fine with CreateBrowserRouter and it is the only code that I changed... CreateBrowserRouter --> CreateHashRouter

Comment: You probably ought to be using the `react-router-dom` `Link` component instead of raw anchor tags so the page isn't being completely reloaded each time.